# How to delete specific chunk of statements with spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

How can I specify the chunk of statements I want to delete? I want to set a limit so that it wouldn't delete all statements at once, but for example X statements, so I could implement logic like delete X statements N times.

```
public interface GeneratedStatementRepository extends JpaRepository<GeneratedStatement, GeneratedStatementId> {

@Modifying
@Transactional
Long deleteByIdCreatedDateBefore(LocalDate expiryDate);           }
```

Comment: It's impossible to write limit queries in hql so your best bet would probably be to use `@Query(nativeQuery = true)` and just write pure sql.

Comment: @InsertKnowledge And how would the query look like then? I would use `LIMIT` or what?

Comment: Yes, since it's native sql you can just do something like `@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "DELETE FROM generated_statements WHERE date < :expiryDate LIMIT 100")`

Comment: @InsertKnowledge Ok, and the Long value that would be returned is the amount of statements deleted? At first it would be 100, and the last time it would be <100, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to return the amount of rows deleted.

Comment: @InsertKnowledge I found some information here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-delete#derived-delete "The return value, of type long, indicates how many records the method deleted." But I'm not sure if that would work in my case

Comment: Yea, well that's when you're using JPA methods. I don't think native queries return that by default so you may need to do` "SELECT COUNT(DELETE FROM...) "` or something like that but once again I'm not absolutely certain about this so let's leave it at that. We want to avoid having an extended discussion in the comments as that is against guidelines.

Comment: @InsertKnowledge Ok, thanks for your help. Just googled that DELETE with LIMIT is not allowed in postresql, which I am using, so I'll be looking for another solution.